# Record audio going to heaphones while listening to it

Tags: linux, audio, microphone, audio-recording, manjaro

Is it possible to record audio (and possibly video, but I can do it separately) going to my headphones plugged in with a jack while also listening to it?
What I'm trying to achieve is recording online lectures while listening with regular headphones.

I'm not trying to use the headphone mic to record the sound coming off the headset but I'm to record the audio before (I think) it goes to the output.

EDIT

```
 $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Please add an OS tag - the solution will depend on the OS you are using,

Comment: Also, tell us what soundcard you are using, because it depends on the soundcard too, if it has a "what you hear" or "stereo mix" recording option.

Comment: Audacity will let you record the audio

Comment: @spikey_richie not if the soundcard does not support it, nor if they are not on windows.

Comment: @dirkt running linux manjaro

Comment: @LPChip I used `arecord -l`, does it provide enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, you'll be likely using Pulseaudio.

If you just want to record everything going to your headphones, just record from the `.monitor` source associated with the sink that is connected to your headphones.

If you want to use `arecord` for that, you have to use something like `pavucontrol` and manually switch it to that source.

You can also use `parecord -d name_of_monitor_source` instead, or any PulseAudio aware recording software, to directly select the source.

Use `pactl list short sources` for a list of all sources, including the `.monitor` ones.